# How to define custom Failure for devise in case of two different models User and active admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, customization, activeadmin

I have two models User and ActiveAdmin on which I want to apply my `devise` integrations.

I have my `custom_failure.rb` as follows

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp

  def redirect_url
    login_path
  end

  # def redirect_url
  #   root_path
  # end

  def respond
    if http_auth?
      http_auth
    else
      redirect
    end
  end
end
```

Which seems to be working great.

Also, can define in my `application controller` like :

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  # case resource
    if resource.is_a?(Admin)
      admin_dashboard_path
    else
      root_path
    end
end
```

and

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  login_path
end
```

But the issue is how to use this `resource` in `custom_failure.rb` so that I can redirect accordingly to login for `user login` or for the `admin login` ?? Acc to current scenario it always redirects to the user login page ??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try putting `custom_failure.rb` into you lib folder. Then make sure the file is loaded. Probably you would attempt to load all files in lib automatically.

Then [Redirect to a specific page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated).

UPDATE:

You have to use **scope** to solve this :-

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp 
  def redirect_url 
    if warden_options[:scope] == :user 
      signin_path 
    else 
      new_admin_user_session_path 
    end 
  end 
  def respond 
    if http_auth? 
      http_auth 
    else 
      redirect 
    end 
  end 
end
```

Comment: I have already done that. My concern was how to identify this custom failure was for a `user` or a `ActiveAdmin`